# How to make a non-action-packed scenes enjoyable

Tags: creative-writing

The specific example that I was thinking of is writing about people traveling through a snow-storm. I tried to write one, and I found myself using phrases like, "The blasting wind blew against their cold faces..."
How can I make a scene like this more diverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a snowstorm, there's bound to be plenty of challenges to write about... are your characters able to see where they're going? If so, how? Is the terrain treacherous? Are they cold, freezing? Is there threat to their lives? Are they committed to the journey, despite the conditions? If so why?

Also, how are they taking it? Are the characters trying to make light of the situation and joking about it? Or are they drawn into conflict and in-fighting? Perhaps merely stoically persisting despite the burden those conditions place upon them.

Basically, the hardship of the snow storm itself can provide plenty of conflict that should make for an entertaining story if you're prepared to explore it's effects.